# Sim800c not receiving the complete SMS

Tags: arduino, stm32, microcontroller, sim800

I am using sim800c module connected to stm32 "bluepill" development board.
I am trying to receive the SMS to be parsed later on. Here is my code:

```
    while(sim800C.available()>0){       
        delay(1000);        
        Received_SMS=sim800A.readString();  
        Serial.print(Received_SMS);}
```

However, the "Received_SMS" string doesn't seem to contain complete message the output is:

```
+CMT: "(number hidden for privacy)","","20/12/03,08:08:54+14"
063306440627
```

The sent sms is much longer than the shown.
I am using the `AT+CSCS="IRA"` but even if I change this AT command the result seems to have a constant length, insufficient for the complete sms.

Thanks for reading the question,
Regards.

Comment: You need to read more lines. The text is after the +CMT line.

Comment: It sure is! the question was "how" to read those lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
    if(sim800A.available()>0){
      while(sim800A.available()>0){
         Received_SMS=sim800A.readString();
      }
    }
```

So, we should put our process in an "if", then a "while".